# list of companies using facebook graph API in a specific region (defined by lat/lng)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If I search for all pages for a particular business (say IBM), the result JSON has many objects, each one's category could be one of "Local business", "Company", "Product/service", "Computers", "Internet/Technology", "Computers/technology" or something else. Which one of these is the company info? or is there a graph API which gives company info?

EDIT: Just to clarify my question further, when I do a get request using this [reference](https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=IBM&type=page), the JSON result is an array of entities, each with unique facebook id. Is there a way to know which one refers to IBM headquarters? or regional offices or something else.

Currently, "category" doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

To what I have seen the facebook API for pages is not very advanced, the [developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) page would be more helpful.